# Unable to run OptaPlanner to optimize a school timetable example in Eclipse

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, optaplanner

I trying to setup the TimeTable example from OptaPlanner ([link here](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#springBootJavaQuickStart)) from copying the needed dependency for Maven and all the relevant code. However, when I try to run it, error occur.

Side note, I trying to copy over the TimeTable to our existing Java Spring Boot version 2.4.5 project.

Below is the error:

[image: Error from Eclipse Console - the error is long but is always referring to no classes found with @PlanningSolution annotation and failed to instantiate SolverConfig. Thus, I only took the last part error.]

Below is my project pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.xtra</groupId>
<artifactId>XtraDelivery</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>XtraDelivery</name>
<description>Java Spring Boot project for the Eurogain web portal for both internal and external client.</description>
<!-- <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties> -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
          <artifactId>optaplanner-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
            <artifactId>optaplanner-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>8.8.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And this is the main application file:

```
package com.xtra.portal;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class XtraDeliveryApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(XtraDeliveryApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

I'm wondering what else I have missed out or ...the example guide is not updated? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What happens if you run our [spring-boot-school-timetabling quickstart from optaplanner-quickstarts](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts/tree/stable/technology/java-spring-boot)? I 'd love to know how the docs differ from that quickstart if the latter works on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this suggestion from the stacktrace you pasted, I suspect that will fix it:

[image]

Comment: Hi Geoffrey, yup, so initially I suspect was due to the maven importing that is broken specifically on getting the repo for optaplanner-spring-boot-starter version 8.8.0.Final as configured in my pom.xml file. So, I did tried to change it to other version such as 8.9.0.Final and 8.7.0.Final, but no different and same error. In fact, there is no compilation error on the TimeTable source code of saying anything such as missing package or Java file for PlanningSolution.

Comment: The optaplanner version doesn't matter. It's about Spring classpath scanning: the package of your `@PlanningSolution` class should be in the same package or a subpackage of your `@SpringBootApplication` class to make this error go away. And probably similar for `@PlanningEntity`.